# Is it masturbation if not intentional

Tags: masturbation

i was puting on a condom for sexual education purposes when i felt an urge. I took the condom off quickly and realised that i had ejaculate. It was not my intention to masturbate so is this haram.

Comment: What do you mean by educational purposes? What form of education is this? What's there to learn brother, even animals know this stuff! But brother if this was sincerely not your intention then we are only judged on our real intentions in the ruling of Islam. The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "The reward of deeds depends upon the intention and every person will get the reward according to what he has intended."

Answer (score -1):

its a forgivable sin, just ask Allah for forgiveness and make sure to not repeat.